# Why are there infinitely many primes $q$ such that $\Bigl(\frac{D_i}{q}\Bigr)=-1$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Consider the discriminants $D_1,D_2,...,D_r$ of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D_i}),D_i<0$.

Why do  infinitely many primes $q$ exist with  $$\Bigl(\frac{D_i}{q}\Bigr)=-1, \ \ \ i=1,..,r?$$

I know that there are infinitely many primes $q$ with $\Bigl(\frac{Di}{q}\Bigr)=-1$ for each  $D_i$.

I think if we consider $$D_1\equiv D_2...\equiv D_r\,(\text{mod}\,q)$$ then all Jacobi symbols are also equal.

Comment: By Chebotarev, there are infinitely many primes $q$ such that Frobenius at $q$ in $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{D_1},\sqrt{D_2},\ldots,\sqrt{D_r})/\mathbf{Q})$ is complex conjugation. Such a prime $q$ satisfies the required condition.

Comment: (For example, take $q \equiv -1 \mod \prod D_i$.)